# Do not want to keep a launcher activity in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Creating an application in which whenever Power is connected or disconnected a small ringtone is played.
But the problem that i am facing is that the application is not working whenever i am not taking any launcher activity.
And when there is a launcher activity than the application is working well.

Comment: the problem is not very clear, can you explain better and probably  share screen shoot or code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh..vague and no code :(

Android does not allow BroadcastReceiver to receive some broadcast info if the app´s process is not alive.It was designed to against the evil apps. If you have an activity running,your process is alive and so your receiver is allowed to receive the broadcast.

You can make a transparent activity and use startService to start a service in background,then finish the activity.As your service is running ,your process is alive,so the Android will let you to receive the broadcast.

The rest of your questions can be directed at the offical docs.